# PL/SQL: SELECT INTO raises ORA-00947

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm using Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

I've created an object type:

```
SQL> create or replace type TestObject as Object (
  2  id INTEGER,
  3  name VARCHAR2(10)
  4  );
  5  /
```

Then I create a table containint objets of that type:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TestTable of TestTable;
```

and I populate the table with some data:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (10, 'John');
```

Now, if I want to perform a SELECT in PL/SQL:

```
SQL> declare
  2  aTest TestObject;
  3  begin
  4  select * into aTest from TestTable;
  5  end;
  6  /
```

I get the error ORA-00947 (not enough values):

```
select * into aTest from TestTable;
                    *
ERROR en línea 4:
ORA-06550: línea 4, columna 21:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: no hay suficientes valores
ORA-06550: línea 4, columna 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

But the TestTable contains objects of type TestObject and the variable aTest is also of type TestObject ... ¿Where is the mismatch in the number of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this worked:

```
declare
 ta TestObject;
begin
 select TestObject(t.id, t.name) into ta from TestTable t;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

```
select TestObject(id,name)  from TestTable
/
```